# Regex - word boundary for any character

Tags: regex, preg-match

i have this code:

```
preg_match("/\b$word\b/ui",$string)
```

it's works fine with letters but the variable can be also sign.. like "!@#$^%+" etc
how can i do it will find this also?

Comment: Do you want to treat characters like `"!@#$^%+"` as "word characters" for the purposes of determining "word boundary"?

Answer (score 3):

Word boundary `\b` is equivalent to:

```
((?<!\w)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?!\w))
```

If you want to treat chars `!@#$^%+` as "word chars" for the purposes of specifying a "word boundary", modify the above expression accordingly:

```
((?<![\w!@#$^%+])(?=[\w!@#$^%+])|(?<=[\w!@#$^%+])(?![\w!@#$^%+]))
```

thus giving you:

```
preg_match("/((?<![\w!@#$^%+])(?=[\w!@#$^%+])|(?<=[\w!@#$^%+])(?![\w!@#$^%+]))$word((?<![\w!@#$^%+])(?=[\w!@#$^%+])|(?<=[\w!@#$^%+])(?![\w!@#$^%+]))/ui",$string)
```

Comment: @warez what do you mean "space boundary"? Do you mean "boundary between space and non-space"? If so, that wouldn't help you match your input because the `$word` is immediately followed by `/ui` - slash is not a space.

Comment: hi , i have string like
"abc.ds gld+s"
i need regex that will found "abc.ds" , "gld+s"
i need the regex will check any word between space

Comment: if you need to match anything between spaces use `\S+` or split on `\s+`